# Restrict selecting file above some size in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, file, android-intent

I a beginner in android, I want to select an image or a video file. But I want to restrict the selected file size, let's assume the restriction size is 5MB. Above 5MB I want to not allow the user to select the file.
How can I do it?
Any help would be appreciated.

Button OnClick:

```
     btnSelectFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            galleryIntent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 21);
        }
    });
```

OnActivityResult:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 21 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Get the Uri of the selected file
        uri = data.getData();


        uriString = uri.toString();
        myFile = new File(uriString);
        path = myFile.getAbsolutePath();
        displayName = null;



        if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    int sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);

                    Log.e("TAG","Size: "+Long.toString(cursor.getLong(sizeIndex)));

                    textFileSelected.setText(displayName);
                    fileName = textFileSelected.getText().toString();

                    Toast.makeText(this, "File Selected: " + fileName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        } else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
            displayName = myFile.getName();
            textFileSelected.setText(displayName);
            fileName = textFileSelected.getText().toString();

            Toast.makeText(this, "File Selected: " + fileName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot prevent the user selecting such a file. You only can act in onActivityResult.

Comment: Why are you only logging the size? You could toast it for the user too.

Comment: Okay, I will do it.